# What is the MLE of the Continuous Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: distributions, exponential-family

The [continuous Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Bernoulli_distribution) is a distribution I recently discovered. What the maximum likelihood estimate of the distribution's parameter? I'm struggling with the normalizing constant.

Comment: Funny; that distribution has been known since at least the 80s. But they have an ICML  2020 paper calling it "novel" in the title.

Comment: Do you have a link to the original work?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy  I came back to your comment to find the proper paper(s) to cite. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the continuous Bernoulli is defined as$$p(x)=C(\lambda)\lambda^x(1-\lambda)^{1-x}\qquad x\in(0,1)\tag{1}$$on [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Bernoulli_distribution), rewriting it as
$$p()\propto \lambda^x(1-\lambda)^{-x} = \{\lambda/(1-\lambda)\}^x=\exp\{\eta x\}$$
shows that it can be reparameterised as an exponential family with natural parameter$$\eta=\log\{\lambda/(1-\lambda)\}.$$The normalising constant is then
$$\int_0^1 \exp\{\eta x\}\,\text dx=\eta^{-1}[e^\eta-1]$$
Given a sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ from (1), the log-likelihood is
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \eta x_i - n \log\{e^\eta-1\}+n\log\eta$$
whose maximum in $\eta$ satisfies
$$\frac{-1}{\hat\eta}+\frac{e^{\hat \eta}}{e^{\hat \eta}-1} = \bar x_n$$
which does not afford a closed-form solution.